# Help with interpreting regression results

Tags: regression

I was running a regression that test the effects of the following variables on BMI in three different states. 1 = Kentucky, 2 = Colorado, 3 = New York.

Each variable was a categorical variable that I factored and converted to numeric. I would a ppreciate if someone can help interpreting the results.
if you need any information to do so let me know in the comments.

````
======================================================================================================
                                                   Dependent variable:                                
                    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           BMI                                        
                               (1)                        (2)                         (3)             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Physical Health             -0.791***                   -0.196*                     -0.251**          
                             (0.208)                    (0.108)                     (0.100)           
                                                                                                      
Sleep Time                   -0.908                     -0.497                       -0.812           
                             (0.906)                    (0.555)                     (0.495)           
                                                                                                      
Exercise                    64.630***                  62.317***                   37.468***          
                            (15.196)                    (9.401)                     (7.283)           
                                                                                                      
Marital Status             -12.708***                 -14.204***                   -11.803***         
                             (4.338)                    (2.152)                     (1.830)           
                                                                                                      
Education                     5.410                     -0.816                     -20.688***         
                             (6.993)                    (4.015)                     (3.294)           
                                                                                                      
Race                         -4.029                    5.479***                      -0.072           
                             (4.625)                    (1.427)                     (1.330)           
                                                                                                      
obese                     1,124.318***               1,018.847***                 1,025.693***        
                            (15.343)                    (9.048)                     (7.735)           
                                                                                                      
Constant                  2,478.559***               2,429.946***                 2,593.758***        
                            (47.956)                   (28.635)                     (23.285)          
                                                                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                  3,659                      9,211                       12,583           
R2                            0.609                      0.593                       0.595            
Adjusted R2                   0.609                      0.593                       0.595            
Residual Std. Error    442.980 (df = 3651)        366.322 (df = 9203)         381.196 (df = 12575)    
F Statistic         813.979*** (df = 7; 3651) 1,919.053*** (df = 7; 9203) 2,642.013*** (df = 7; 12575)
======================================================================================================
Note:                                                                      *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! 1) I don't see the state in your regression output. Did you meant to omit the state? // 2) In what software did you do this?

Comment: Look at the top the numbers are the states I just haven't labeled them, Kentucky = 1 Colorado is 2 and New york = 3, I used R.

Comment: I used stargazer, and tidyverse.

Comment: Please update your closed question from earlier today to include this information.

Comment: Please stop reposting your question.  Consult our [help], follow its advice, and *edit* your original question to clarify your situation.